# Why is this query working in the mongo shell but not the node mongo driver?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm successfully running this query in the shell:

```
db.hourlydatas.find({'timeseries':ObjectId('1234')})
```

Trying to translate it to the mongo driver:

```
MongoClient.connect(config.db, function(err, db) {
// Use the admin database for the operation

var collection = db.collection('hourlydatas');

collection.find({'timeseries':'1234'}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
//   assert.equal(err, null);
console.log("Found the following records");
console.log(docs);
// callback(docs);
});      

});
```

This does not return any documents, I assume because I'm not converting the string to an objectID.  Is this possible in the driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var collection = db.collection('hourlydatas');
collection.find({'timeseries':ObjectId('1234')}).toArray(function(err,docs) {...}
```

Comment: It's not actually an integer, its and object ID string.  The actual objectid is a long string like 5019ijasWQa231, but I changed it for simplicity

Answer (score 0):

It should work, are you sure you are connecting to the same DB? check if both connections are to test or prod... I once wasted a lot of time on this just to find at the end that my mongo-shell was connected to prod while node was connecting to test.